# Adding a plugin SDK - Multiple inheritance or not?

Tags: c++, plugins, sdk, multiple-inheritance

I have a 3D C++ app, with a scene graph. All scene graph objects inherit the superclass `Node`. The next inheritance levels are base classes such as `Geometry`, `Material`, `Light`, `Camera` which all inherit `Node`. Then, the actual scene objects are of types such as `FisheyeCamera`, `PhongMaterial`, `PointLight`, `SpotLight` which as the names suggest inherit from the corresponding base classes. Quite simple, no multiple inheritance.

Now I am adding a SDK, allowing users expanding the software with new classes. The base classes (`Camera`, `Light`, ...) are exposed through interfaces (classes with only pure virtual functions) such as `CameraInterface`, `LightInterface`

Plugin developpers use these interface classes in two ways:

- For creating new node types by subclassing them. In the main app I have the corresponding `PluginCamera`, `PluginLight`, etc... which are wrappers to the interfaces exposed by the plugin
- For accessing other scene nodes. **This is the important point**

This was made with pure virtual only interfaces for two reasons:

- For avoiding compiler incompatibilities when calling member functions, as classes with only pure virtual member functions are all implemented the same way by windows targeting compilers
- To avoid exposing the full classes to the SDK

**Now, the question** : I first tried to implement everything by avoiding multiple inheritance. But as `Camera` does not inherit `CameraInterface`, accessing it from a plugin requires the app to create and manage an accessor inheriting `CameraInterface` and using a pointer on the `Camera` object. This starts working but was much more complex than expected. Now I am thinking about allowing virtual inheritance so that every app node has a plugin interface.

Is that a good idea? I'm asking before trying, as the app code is quite large and contains a lot of node classes (more than 100) so implementing the full SDK will take some time... Thinking before may be a good idea.

Performance is critical, the app is already highly optimized. There are no casts or RTTI during the computing : the scene is frozen and all node pointers initialized before the heavy work starts. Adding levels of indirection for function calls appears to have a noticeable impact on performance (as a node class is a few % slower implemented as a plugin than as a native app code)

Answer (score 0):

**Structure**

The idea of using multiple inheritance is perfectly valid here:

- A `Camera` **is-a** node, and at the same time **is-a** plugin object which implements the `CameraInterface`.
- The difficulty that you experience with accessor and bidirectional link from `Camera` to `CameraInterface` (to syncrhonize at least the lifetime) and from `CameraInterface` to `Camera` (to allow plugin to manipulate the real object) confirms that inheritance is structurally more adapted here than composition.

Virtual inheritance needs to be assessed carefully:

- at first sight, it seems not necessary: your example seems to accredit the hypotheses that only the final graphic elements inherit from plugin hierarchy, i.e. the note and the plugin inheritance hierarchies are not interleaved.
- it could however be required if the reality is more complex, and escpecially if all graphic elements could inherit from plugin elements at any levels.  In this case without virtuality, you'd have several instances of plugin in the same object, which doesn't seem to make sense.

Virtual inheritance would make it slightly more complex, as you have alwys to initailise explicitely the common virtual bases.

**Performance**:

With multiple inheritance, you'll have several [vtables](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/multiple-inheritance-considered-useful/184402074) for accessing virtual functions (one for each inheritance hierarchy).  However, for a given pointer type, the implementation will only **access a single vtable** with a single offset.  Thus performance will not be more degraded than single inheritance with virtual functions.

In addition you can compare with the single inheritance alternative that you have explored.  You'll notice that navigation between objects and their adpaters will need a lot of pointer dereferencing, which might balance out the vtable indirection (and only if you would'nt make use of virtual functions).